# android there is no event when clicking a button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I have an activity which has a button, I want when press the button to toast something, I did that like this :

```
public class myActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText nameEditText;
    Button okButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        nameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button:
            Toast.makeText(myActivity.this, "Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

where is the wrong?

thank you

Comment: You forgot to assign listener yo your button e.q. `okButton.setOnClickListener(this);` this is reason why no event is fired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you forget to set the listener for your button

because your activity is already implementing `onClickListener` interface so you have to put `okButton.setOnClickListener(this);` after `okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);` in your `onCreate` function. check the following code please:

#### myActivity.java

```
public class myActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

        EditText nameEditText;
        Button okButton;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            nameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
                okButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button:
                Toast.makeText(myActivity.this, "Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the meaning of setonclicklistener? I already implement onclicklistener to myActivity

Comment: when you implement a listener that doesn't mean you set the listener to all your widgets, you also have to set that listener to your widgets in order to make that listener triggered the event from that widget

Answer (score 2):

on your onCreate method you have to add a register

```
okButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

after

```
okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `okButton = setOnClickListenre(this)` because your activity implements on click listener. Insert this code after `okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);`